# why does it wrong when I use keyword inline decorating the construct function?

Tags: c++, inline

for example:

```
#include "ist1.h"
class ist2:public ist1
{
public:
    inline ist2();
    int y;
    void say();

};
```

I think that the keyword "inline" is a explicit "suggestion" to compiler instead of an order,but why it says error ?why the compiler doesn't ignore "inline"?

Comment: What's the point of actually posting the error message, right? C++ only has one... :|

Comment: Well.. as it is, it's a substring of a valid C++ program, so I guess we need more context.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore If there is an error in the code, the compiler outputs `"?"` and terminates.  A competent programmer will know what is wrong.  (Paraphrased from an early manual for `ed`, the original Unix editor.  Whose only error message was `?`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell us what the error is; there is no error in the code you've posted.

Possibly, you're getting an "undefined reference" (or similar) error from the linker. This would be because an inline function must be defined in every translation unit that uses it so, in practice, you'll have to put the definition in the header rather than a source file.

If the error is something else, then please tell us what it is.

> I think that the keyword "inline" is a explicit "suggestion" to compiler instead of an order

That's a common misconception. Although it might be used as a hint when the compiler decides whether or not to inline it, it also has a semantic meaning:

- An inline function *may* be defined in more than one translation unit, as long as all the definitions are identical. Normal functions may only have a single definition within the program.
- An inline function *must* be defined in every translation unit that uses it.

Comment: thx，I found it's a linking problem as you said.And I have no ideal about translation unit,could you tell me something about it？

Comment: The C++ standard seems to share his point of view: the first thing it says about `inline` is that it tells the compiler that the programmer thinks that generating the code inline would be preferable.

Comment: @Bruce: Your introductory C++ book should explain that. Simplifying slightly, a "translation unit" is a single source file, along with all the headers it includes.

Comment: And by the way: good guessing as to the actual problem.  Without the error message, it wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed it does; but the semantic meaning is rather more important than vague words about indicating preferences. The "misconception" I refer to is that it's *only* purpose is to give a hint to the compiler.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Introductory C++ books are notorious for not using the same vocabulary as the standard.  It's likely that the book called it a modulo or a compilation unit or some other invented term.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes.  Things like `inline` can be a bit tricky, because the intent and the actual formal semantics are so different (and could easily seem unrelated to a novice).  But the intent is important, since it is the only motivation for using `inline`.  (One could easily argue that _any_ use of inline before the profiler has spoken is premature optimization.)

Comment: I had another question.If I could define a macro like  #define inline      that I macro the inline as space and I use inline defaultly. P.S:let alone my English grammar :P

Comment: @Bruce: That macro would be a bad idea: it would break any code that (correctly) defined an inline function in a header, and included that header in multiple source files. By using the preprocessor to remove the `inline` specifier, you'll end up with multiple definitions of a non-inline function, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

inside `inline type func();` (note the ; at end) there is no code to inline.

It would make sense if you define the function, but:

- member function *defined* (with a body!) inside a class block are inlied by default and
- member function defined outside the class block and in a separated source must not be inlined (or cannot be linked).

As a consequence explicitly inlined member functions makes sense only if defined outside the class block  but inside the header.

The idea that `inline` is a "suggestion" for the compiler is just misleading and arcaic. (Think a while: you "suggest" something every platform can do better or elsewhere: isn't it time to drop from the standard definition this meaningless oxymoron?)

`inline` actually means "this definition may appear multiple times inside different translation units".

And is required for non-template global-level defined functions (member or not) defined in headers. Everything else is just "noise".

Comment: It's not just noise and it's not used just for global functions. Declaration like that is used to declare inline member functions when they are defined outside of the class within the same header.

Comment: This is simply wrong.  Member functions defined within the class (you cannot define a function in a block) are implicitly inline, but you can declare them explicitly inline as well.  Member functions defined outside the class can be inline; some coding guidelines I've seen require this.  The `inline` may appear on the declaration in the class definition, or on the definition (which must be in the header as well).  And the idea that `inline` is a suggestion for the compiler is the first thing the standard says about `inline`.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: yes, that's correct. My idea stands for "defined at global level". Ill'edit in that sense

Comment: @JamesKanze: It is so "simply wrong" that "simply works". If you are a language lawyer, that's OK, but frankly... There is the risk only language lawyers will understand!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia The poster asked why he got an error.  You posted a bunch of erroneous statements which either don't answer his question, or answer it incorrectly.  (The only correct thing to say about his code is that the part he showed us is completely legal.)

Comment: My assumptions are now confirmed.